# Is there any PDF field/element that can be used for grouping multiple elements?

Tags: pdf, itext, field, grouping, element

Is there any PDF field/element that can be used for grouping purpose (like Panel or Section etc.) of multiple elements.

I want to group some elements (Text fields, check boxes, buttons etc.) and use the group's name to take some decision.

Or what can be other options to achieve this goal?

Comment: Please specify "decision"… One possibility to group fields is using hierarchical field names, where the parts of the field names are separated by the period character. This allows to set some field properties at once (such as display or readonly).

Comment: @MaxWyss I have to get the type of field and place an image on field's location. For example if the field type is checkbox, I will put a custom checkbox image on that location. For the group element I will get the group type and place an image on group's location. Which means I also want to know the position of the group element.